# Flexbox two columns grid not works

Tags: css, flexbox

Its very simple, I want a two columns grid with flexbox, I read some code examples [like this](https://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-column) but my code not work.

You can check the flex grid here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ew9rjuq/3/

This is the css:

```
.mini-product-detail {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.mini-product-detail .mini-item {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap: wrap;`..

Also used `box-sizing: border-box;` for the items.

```css
 .mini-product-detail {
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.mini-product-detail .mini-item {
border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
background-color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 24px;
padding: 10px;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mini-product-detail">
        
 <div class="mini-item"></div>
 <div class="mini-item"></div>
 <div class="mini-item"></div>
 <div class="mini-item"></div>
```